# Datepicker whole Calendar not displaying all dates within html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, struts2

I have an html table with the following 2 columns within a logic:iterate :

```
<logic:notPresent name="divisionLevel"><td><input type="text" name="txtBeginDate${ctr+1}" id="txtBeginDate${ctr+1}" class="is-datepick" style="width: 100%;" value="<bean:write name="row" property="reportingBeginDte"/>"/></td></logic:notPresent>
<logic:notPresent name="divisionLevel"><td><input type="text" name="txtEndDate${ctr+1}" id="txtEndDate${ctr+1}" class="is-datepick" style="width: 100%;" value="<bean:write name="row" property="reportingEndDte"/>"/></td></logic:notPresent>
```

The problem is that the calendar, when you click on the date, shows only the left half.  I've tried some `z-index`ing, as well as only having a few divs but no matter what I try it's still the partial datepicker.

Screenshot of the partial calendar look:

[image]

UPDATE: SOLVED! Thank you to everyone who took the time to help out. To fix, I added the table id on the display:none style:

```
#maintable td:nth-child(1){ display : none;}
#maintable td:nth-child(2){ display : none;}
#maintable td:nth-child(3){ display : none;}
#maintable td:nth-child(4){ display : none;}
```

Comment: There appears to be more to this question than just the tags you've put on there, as `logic:notPresent` is not valid HTML, nor is `<bean:write.../>` a valid attribute value. Please tag the appropriate framework you're using so that the appropriate experts can take a look.

Comment: It seems to be jsp framework, right? Anyway, some of the people (including myself) are not familiar with this framework so we can't help you. But also, maybe it's not relevant. If you will post the output html (just how it looks in the browser), or even better, create a [runnable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/863110) snippet that reproduce the problem, we may can help.

Comment: Did the F12 Developer Tools tell you something?

Comment: Thanks all. I believe the framework is Struts but I didn't think that mattered but maybe it does. I'll update the tag. I'll post the output html for now and try to make a runnable snippet.

Comment: So the framework looks like Struts 1 to me.  [old docs here](https://people.apache.org/~germuska/struts-taglib/docs/tlddoc/index.html), better docs in the zip file [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/struts/documentation/). Basically the logic:present tag is checking on the request/session and page scope to see if the 'divisionLevel' exists. The bean:write prints the respective property to the page. I would consider doing the opposite logic:present next to the other with style="background-color: red;" and see what you get.

Comment: This portion 'name="txtBeginDate${ctr+1}"' is Expression language I think, and its probably just getting the counter value from your logic:iterate and adding 1 to make the html input element name and id unique.

Comment: Am maybe its tje jQuery UI Datepicker? Either way the jsp struts 1 and EL tags are just putting a text input down for the datepicker to be tied to when clicked. I can't imagine this has much todo with the calendar itself. That is likely tied to where the Datepicker is declared. $(".is-datepick").datepicker(); Maybe with some custom JavaScript?

Comment: I finally figured out what was causing it, and it was by accident how I figured it out! 
I'm hiding my 1st 3 columns via the following:
`td:nth-child(1){ display : none;}
td:nth-child(2){ display : none;}
td:nth-child(3){ display : none;}`

By each of those, it's also hiding columns of the date picker! I added a 4th hidden column and noticed a 4th column gone on the date picker, removed all 4 display : nones and now the whole calendar appears!  Now I just have to figure out how to hide those columns without messing up the date picker :D

Comment: UPDATE: SOLVED! Thank you to everyone who took the time to help out. To fix, I added the table id on the display:none style:

    #maintable td:nth-child(1){ display : none;}
    #maintable td:nth-child(2){ display : none;}
    #maintable td:nth-child(3){ display : none;}
    #maintable td:nth-child(4){ display : none;}